# Do the French say you're "in your 60s" when you're in your 70s?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Give that 70 in French is *soixante-dix*, do the French say that a 70-year-old is still in their 60s? The same question goes for someone in their 90s - are they said to be in their 80s? Or is there a different expression for it?

Answer (score 7):

No, we would never say of a 75 year-old man that he has ***une soixantaine d'années*** or just ***la soixantaine***.

Theoretically, we might use "**soixante-dizaine**", "**quatre-vingtaine**" and "**quatre-vingt-dizaine**" but it's very rare.

We rather say, *il a **soixante-dix ans passé***, ***quatre-vingts ans passé***, or ***quatre-vingt-dix ans passé***.

In Switzerland and Belgium ***septantaine*** and ***nonantaine*** are much better, and *[**huitantaine**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/huitantaine)* too when used.

Comment: Et aussi *il a dans les soixante-dix ans* (mais c'est vrai que ça n'encadre pas et ça pourrait faire 69...)

Answer (score 5):

In French, the most common way to vaguely refer to one's age is by quoting the category :

- un ou une vingtenaire (vingt means 20): someone aged between 20 and 29
- trentenaire (trente = 30): between 30 and 39
- quarantenaire (quarante = 40): between 40 and 49
- cinquantenaire (cinquante = 50): between 50 and 59
- soixantenaire (soixante = 60): between 60 and 69

there is indeed no obvious following-up (you wouldn't call someone a "soixante-dixenaire" nor a "quatre-vingtenaire").

For older people, there is another series of words that works the same way and even overlaps. When used for people below 70, this series tends to present them as older.

- quadragénaire: between 40 and 49
- quinquagénaire: between 50 and 59
- sexagénaire: between 60 and 69
- septuagénaire: between 70 and 79
- octagénaire: between 80 and 89
- nonagénaire: between 90 and 99

then there is "centenaire" for people above 100 years old. More technical terms exist after that but are rarely used.

Comment: De _vingtenaire_ à _soixantenaire_, on n'utilise pas trop, si?

Comment: I agree these words do exist but I would not say it's "the most common way" to refer to an age range. In my opinion it's much more common to say *il a la trentaine/la quarantaine etc...* and for someone between 70 & 80 *il a entre 70 et 80 ans*. And since you want to cover a wider range of age groups than what is asked in the question you could have mentioned the colloquial *quadra* and *quinqua*. Besides *septantenaire*, *huitantenaire* and *nonantenaire* are common in Belgium and Switzerland, I've also sometimes heard *nonantenaire* in France.

Comment: "the most common way" section is wrong. Of the list, only "trentenaire" is used. For other decades, the second list is used (and for 40 and 50, often abbreviated "quadra" and "quinqua"). Cinquentenaire (and the others)  are used to refer the the exact anniversary of an event. For example: "1995 marque le cinquentenaire de la libération"